# Validation failure tex2D HLSL Shader Model 6.0

Tags: c++, hlsl, pixel-shader, directx-12

So apparently tex2D is still supported in HLSL shaderModel 6.0 so why does doing something like the following produce validation errors:

```
float myFloat = tex2D(MySampler, In.texCoord).w;
```

It does not like  tex2D, if I make a Texture2D MyTex variable 1st then do 
    MyFloat = MyTex.Sample(MySampler, In.texCoord).w; validation is fine.

Of course I have disables validation with /Vd and dxc spits out a compiled file but no .asm when specified, dxc also tends to jam up with tex2D usage....

I have tried compilation with multiple versions of dxc.exe

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What validation errors?

Comment: Are you building with ``/Gec`` (Enable backward compatibility mode)?

Comment: @Chuck Walbourn /Gec is depricated in 6.0 and above

Comment: @SurvivalMachine validation errors are:
Never resolved value found in function
Validation failed. It complains about tex2D always